# Can I use built-in and external audio interfaces together?

Tags: audio

My band is using live backing tracks with songs. And our audio interface(Scarlett Solo) has only two outputs. Because of that, we need to use one of them for mono backing track and one of them for clicks.

Now, we want to raise it to three outputs so we can send backing tracks as two outputs(as stereo).

I tried ASIO4ALL but it made latency, a lot. Can I send my clicks over headphone out without sending from unbalanced outputs? Or can I send my clicks over laptop's built-in headphone output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your software but generally yes you can. The problem you’re probably having is that the capabilities and performance of built in sounds cards is usually much less than dedicated audio interfaces. Built in audio usually doesn’t support high sample rates and may have a lot more latency than dedicated audio interfaces.

The ideal solution is an audio interface with more outputs.